# Trying "SUPERCLASS NULL"

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to remove superclass from a class.  The ODB manual says "NULL to remove it." but it gives me this error:

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass is null"
```

Here is an example that illustrates the problem:

```
create class test extends V
alter class test superclass NULL
```

I'm using OrientDB release: orientdb-community-2.1.9

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says:

Remove a super-class:

orientdb> ALTER CLASS Employee SUPERCLASS -Person

This feature was introduced in version 2.1.

You can look the documentation at the following link
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Alter-Class.html

Answer (score 2):

For ODB 2.1 at least, the manual is wrong regarding NULL, but you can use + to add and - to remove a superclass, e.g.:

```
> create class test extends V
> create class subtest extends test

> alter class subtest superclass -test
Class updated successfully
```